# Look at the last edited information of a Plist file

Tags: iphone, plist, editing

Is there any way you can get the last edited time off a file? I have a pList on a server that download to my app. I would like to look at the time it was last edited. Do I have to implement a specific key, or can you look at the pLists information from within the app?

Comment: On a business-trip, coming home to try it in the weekend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
NSString *pathName; //assuming you already have this
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:pathName error:nil];
NSDate *editDate = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
```